# How many items has a multi-value field?

Tags: 7

I need to loop through all the values of a multi field as per example bellow:

`for ($i = 1; $i < ???; $i++) {`

```
    $a = $form['field_...']['und'][$i]['#entity']->field_...['und'][0]['value'];
```

}

of course I could do something like this

`foreach ($form['field_additional_sections']['und'] as $key=>$value) {

   if (is_int($key)) {

    ....
   }

}`

but I was wondering if there is a nicer option to do this. I should probably mention that I'm implementing **hook_FORM_ID_form_alter**.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`element_children()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/element_children/7) is the easiest way to get a list of all child elements in a render array, e.g.

```
foreach (element_children($form['field_...'][LANGUAGE_NONE]) as $key) {
  $element = $form['field_...'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$key];
}
```

Comment: Why not a simple `count($form['field_...'][LANGUAGE_NONE])` ?

Comment: @GregoryKapustin _I need to loop through all the values of a multi field_...can't do that with a count :)

Comment: I was thinking about `for ($i = 1; $i < count(...); $i++) {`

Comment: @GregoryKapustin The actual children are mixed with FAPI-specific array items. I.e. the items which has keys starting with a # sign. element_children solves that specific problem by checking if the first character of the array key is a #.